# Inconsistent RSA encryption length result

Tags: ios, objective-c, openssl, rsa

i'm using external library OpenSSL-Universal for encrypting password using RSA_PKCS1_PADDING. Unfortunately the output of char encoded result have an inconsistent length. Let say i have 2048 bit modulus the length result i expect is 128 otherwise it will be failed to decrypt back to plain text.

```
BIGNUM *xponent = BN_new();
    BIGNUM *modulus = BN_new();
    BN_hex2bn(&xponent,xponentInHex);
    BN_hex2bn(&modulus,modInHex);

    RSA *rsa = RSA_new();
    rsa->e = xponent;
    rsa->n = modulus;
    char encoded[1024] = {0};

    RSA_public_encrypt(
        (int)strlen(charString),// from len
        (const unsigned char *)charString, // from
        (unsigned char *)encoded, // to
        rsa,
        RSA_PKCS1_PADDING
    );

    RSA_free(rsa);
NSLog(@"%lu", strlen(encoded));
```

if there is anything wrong with my implements or if you have some explanation about inconsistent length result please let me know

Answer (score 2):

Encrypted Output from `RSA_public_encrypt` is **not a string**, so you cannot check it's length using `strlen`. I hope you do realize that strlen will consider any '\0' seen in your encrypted output as end of string and will return the numbers of bytes till that point as length of the string. But, encrypted buffer can have valid bytes which can be '\0'.

Also, please note that RSA_public_encrypt returns the length of the encrypted data, which you should be using.

Comment: i assume you haven't try using universal-openssl pod.

Comment: My answer is based on your post: NSLog(@"%lu", strlen(encoded));. So, I assume you are using strlen. But, RSA_public_encrypt cannot be return a string.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [Objective-C-RSA](https://github.com/ideawu/Objective-C-RSA) third-party libraries,Or read the source code and then realize by yourself.

Comment: hummm.. actually i implement rsa using openssl-universal cause i already have modulus key and exponent. But thanks for advice